# string convert to date time in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I have a list of date time strings like this.

`16-Aug-2019`

I want to convert the string to `2019-08-01` this date format, and I have tried on this code , but it's getting me an error.

`formatd_date = datetime.strptime(formatd_date, '%y-%m-%d')`

`ValueError: time data 'As-of' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'`

If any can help, it will be huge thank.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime#466376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to datetime format and then convert to string format you want to:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = "16-Aug-2019"
>>> datetime.strptime(a, "%d-%b-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2019-08-16'
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Thank you for saving me.  It's working properly @subhrajyoti-das

Answer (score 1):

Just fails because %y is 2-digit year. Use %Y for 4-digit year.